# Run existing .sql file from Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, excel-2010, export-to-excel

I have a .sql file which contains a `select` statement. Is there a way to directly import/run this query in Excel? I can edit the "Command text" in the "Connection Properties" of an existing database connection, but this requires copying and pasting the .sql code. Browsing and selecting the file I want would be very helpful.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and Excel 2010.

Comment: Hi, how are you connecting to the sql server - windows authentication or sql server authentication?

Comment: also, http://www.connectionstrings.com/ is a great resource for this

Answer (score -1):

I would read it into a variable first, then you can use it in the query. Use something like this:

```
strPath = "P:\...sql"
Open strPath For Binary As #1
MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
Get #1, , MyData
Close #1
```

Now you have the query in the MyData variable. You may need to reformat it to remove line returns before you try to run it.